# Problema con FirebaseDatabase apk-release Android

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

Cuando hago las pruebas con apk-debug los datos se almacenan con su clave correcta en FirebaseDatabase, tal cual como la estipulo en el modelo.

Pero cuando genero el apk-release, se guardan los datos pero con claves diferentes.

En la imagen adjunta marco en verde como quedan quedan los datos con el apk-debug y en rojo como esta quedando cuando genero la app en apk-release.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Saben por que se presenta esto? y ¿Que debería modificar para resolverlo?

Gracias de antemano a todos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes configurar ProGuard para que mantenga los nombres de las propiedades de tus modelos.

Según la [documentación de Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/) debes agregar esta configuración a tu archivo `proguard-rules.pro`:

```
# Add this global rule
-keepattributes Signature

# This rule will properly ProGuard all the model classes in
# the package com.yourcompany.models. Modify to fit the structure
# of your app.
-keepclassmembers class com.yourcompany.models.** {
  *;
}
```

(donde `com.yourcompany.models.**` es el paquete en el que se encuentran tus modelos)

Comment: Así es, eso lo leí el fin de semana pero quizás algo me quedó mal en la implementación, volveré a probar.